# Dynamics CRM onpremise F5 issues open new record

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We have an on-premise CRM version 8.2. Which was migrated from 2011 version. For the few custom entity while pressing F5 it opens a new record. Instead of refreshing the already created open record.

Came across the below link. But the resolution says close and open it. Which is currently we are doing as work around. But I need a solution to fix. Any help will be appreciated.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/hitting-f5-key-on-appointment-opens-new-record-in-crm-2011-post-ur5-fec3920a-19a6-1c56-bf3a-530c8c9ba7b7

Comment: do you have any onload script for few of your custom entities? may be onload script does something?.

Comment: @AnkUser No disabled all the script file. But still getting the same issue.

Comment: your best bet is MS support ticket.